# Can't store encrypted Connection Strings in app .exe.config file?

Tags: visual-studio, connection-string, configuration-files, password-encryption, configurationmanager

As far as I can tell, if you want to dynamically build and then encrypt a Connection String, it's not possible to use the application Configuration File for storing them if you need to be able to alter the Connection String after compile-time.

Just to clarify, here's what I'm trying to achieve:

- I want to deploy a client program to locations anywhere - so I don't know their database server names and passwords
- The connection string details must therefore be added later by whoever deploys the program
- All users of the program will have to access the database using the same username
- I need to encrypt the connection string because customers don't want passwords to be visible
- The encryption string needs to contain the password

So, I would like my program to prompt the user for a server name, username, pwd etc, then create the connection string and store it encrypted in the .config file

Here's my understanding of how My.Settings handles ConnectionStrings:

- The ConnectionStrings section in the program's .config file can be encrypted (e.g. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ) (I have this working fine)
- However, to get a Connection String into the .config file's section, it must be stored as a ConnectionString in My.Settings
- Connection Strings in MySettings are Application scope - so they can't be changed at run-time

So, it appears that you can encrypt a Connection String, but only if you know what the Connection String is when you're writing the program.

If you're a customer and you want to edit the ConnectionString, you can't edit the .config file (because it's encrypted), and the program itself can't change the connection string and store it into the .config file.

Is this correct?  Is there no way to use the app config file encryption capability to store a connection string that's built at run-time?

Comment: Thanks, T.S., for your comment. I decided that My.Settings wasn't viable for storing a connection string that is changed by the application itself.  So, I've stored it into its own XML config file, and encrypted the password before storing it.  This excellent example from Microsoft was very helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172831.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have few options here. First - use machine encryption for the connection string. And [I believe] it will even work on the web farm if you set same machine key on each participating server.

Another thing what you can do is to write custom configuration section handler [Custom Config Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which knows how to encrypt/decrypt items in the specific section. You need a vector, which you can write directly in the handler itself, and the key. The key could be a software license key you provide to your customer. You can make key on fly, from serialized file or assembly. With custom section it will work just fine, and it will be harder for users to understand where and what comes from where.